# Getting Error 1814 Extracting from Resource

Tags: c++, winapi, resources

Trying to Load an Executable from Resource, I get error 1814 and i obviously dont seem to understand why this is so.
My source code looks like this

**Resource.h**

```
IDR_EXE1 EXE  "C:\\Users\\*****\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\HelloWorldMessageBoxExample\\Debug\\HelloWorldMessageBoxExample.exe"
```

Now My source code to Load it from Resource looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "resource.h"

int main()
{
    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    HRSRC hrsrc = FindResource(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE("IDR_EXE1"), L"EXE");

    if (hrsrc == NULL) {
        printf("Error finding Resource, Reason :%d", GetLastError());
        getchar();
    }
    HGLOBAL hLoaded = LoadResource(NULL, hrsrc);
    if (hLoaded == NULL) {
        printf("Error Loading Resource, Reason: %d", GetLastError());
        getchar();
    }
    LPVOID lpLock = LockResource(hLoaded);
    if (lpLock == NULL) {
        printf("Error Loading Locking Resource, Reason: %d", GetLastError());
        getchar();
    }
    DWORD dwSize = SizeofResource(NULL, hrsrc);
    if (dwSize == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot Get Size of Resource, Reason: %d", GetLastError());
        getchar();
    }
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"C:\\Users\\*******\\AppData\\Local\\vaxi\\hiMsg.exe", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hFile == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot Create File,Reason : %d", GetLastError());
        getchar();
    }
    DWORD dwBytesWritten;
    if (!WriteFile(hFile, lpLock, dwSize, &dwBytesWritten, NULL))
    {
        printf("Write File Failed,Reason : %d", GetLastError());
    }
    if (!CloseHandle(hFile))
    {
        printf("Close Handle Failure, Reason: %d", GetLastError());
    }
    else {
        printf("Extracted Correctly!\n");
    }
    if (!ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", (char*)hFile, 0, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL)) {
        printf("Shell Execute Failed, Reason: %d", GetLastError());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And i still get the error 1814 what exactly can be wrong here?

Comment: Not everyone knows / remembers what a 1814 error is. Please always copy the exact text of the error message and add that to your question. If this is Visual Studio copy that from the Output tab. No pictures of text please.

Comment: When I compile `MAKEINTRESOURCE("IDR_EXE1")` I get [warning C4302](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-2-c4302?view=vs-2017) (conversion from a larger to a smaller type). It turns out, compiler warnings can actually be useful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error code [1814](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--1700-3999-) is `ERROR_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND`:

> The specified resource name cannot be found in the image file.

The error is correct. `MAKEINTRESOURCE("IDR_EXE1")` produces the wrong name, so there is no resource found.  You are misusing the [`MAKEINTRESOURCE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648029.aspx) macro. The correct use is `MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_EXE1)` instead.